# Install SSL certificates in Apache Tomcat server - Keystore preparation is required?

Tags: ssl, tomcat, certificate, ssl-certificate, keystore

Im trying to import SSL certificates in apache tomcat server.

Env: Ubuntu

Server: Apache tomcat

The domain service provider sent to me the following files:

- private RSA key
- CSR file

After issuing the SSL certificate, SSL provider (COMODO) sent to me the actual certificate files (root/intermediate .crt files)

So my questions are:

1. Since i haven't generated the CSR and RSA private key by myself and therefore i havent prepared any keystore, how should i import the certificates in JRE? Should i have to use the jre\lib\security\cacerts keystore ?
2. Should i have to convert my .crt files to a different format in order to be supported by Tomcat?

Comment: Check this out https://www.ssls.com/knowledgebase/how-to-install-an-ssl-certificate-on-a-tomcat-server/

Hope it helps !

Comment: Thank you, the question is which keystore should i select in the -keystore param of the keytool command?

Comment: I think you have to select the keystore that you specify in your server.xml file. The idea here is, it generates the jks file with certificates in it and you should let tomcat know where is the jks file. I think server.xml is where you specify the keystore file path i guess. you can also refer this - https://www.digicert.com/kb/csr-ssl-installation/tomcat-keytool.htm

Comment: Did it resolve your issue??